# Реализовать оператор [][]

Tags: c++, ооп

Всем добрый день. Не могу понять, почему мой код не проходит тесты на stepik.org, хотя локально работает.
Буду рад советам.

> В этой задаче вам требуется реализовать оператор [] для уже известного вам класса String. Однако на этот раз оператор должен реализовывать нестандартное поведение: оператор нужно реализовать таким образом, чтобы для объекта str класса String можно было писать str[i][j] и это выражение возвращало подстроку начинающуюся в позиции i (считая с 0) и заканчивающуюся в позиции j (не включая).
>
> String const hello("hello");
> String const hell = hello[0][4]; //теперь в hell хранится подстрока "hell"
> String const ell  = hello[1][4]; // теперь в ell хранится подстрока
> "ell"
>
> Обратите внимание, что i может равняться j, в этом случае результатом
> должна быть пустая строка. Гарантируется, что i никогда не будет
> больше j, и они не будут выходить за пределы длины строки.

```
struct String {
String(const char *str = "");
String(size_t n, char c);
~String();

String(const String &other);
String &operator=(const String &other);
void append(const String &other);

    struct SubString {

    SubString(const char* str = "", const int index= 0) :size(0), tmp_String(nullptr)
    {
        size_old = strlen(str);
        size = strlen(str + index);
        SubString::str = new char[size + 1];
        sprintf(SubString::str, "%s", str + index);
    }
        
   ~SubString()
    {
       delete[] str; 
       delete [] str_tmp;
       if ( tmp_String)
           delete tmp_String;
    }

    String operator[] (const int index) {

        size_t new_len = index - ( size_old - size);
        str_tmp = new char[new_len+1];
        memcpy(str_tmp, str, new_len);
        str_tmp[new_len] = '\0';
        
        tmp_String = new String(str_tmp);
        return *tmp_String;         
    }
private:
    size_t size, size_old;
    char* str, *str_tmp;
    String * tmp_String;
                            
};

    SubString  operator[] (const int index) const {

    return  SubString(str, index);
}

size_t size;
char *str;
```

};

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я вижу у себя под MVS, все деструкторы вызываются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three ну и бардак с памятью

Comment: Утечка памяти в операторе `[]`. Если два раза её вызвать то предыдущее значение `tmp_String` будет висеть в памяти. Перед присвоением нужно удалить предыдущую строку. С `str_tmp` та-же проблема.

Answer (score 1):

У вас изначально не совсем верная идея. Это задача на паттерн proxy, т.е. нужно создать класс, который содержит ссылку на исходную строку и индекс начала подстроки, и перегрузить у него operator[].

Использование new для новой строки тоже избыточно, т.к. сам массив символов уже лежит в динамической памяти. Если боитесь лишнего глубокого копирования, перегрузите оператор перемещения и погуглите оптимизацию возвращаемый значения.

Должно получиться что-то подобное:

```
class String{
    size_t size;
    const char *data;
public:
    // Конструировать лучше из указателя и длины строки, чтобы удобно было брать подстроку
    String(const char* chars, size_t size); // Глубокое копирование
    String(const String& other); // Глубокое копирование
    String(String&& other); // Перемещение, нужно просто скопировать указатель и размер, и обнулить указатель в other

    class StringRangeProxy{
        const String& src;  
        size_t begin;
    public:
        StringRangeProxy(const String& src_, size_t begin_)
            : src(src_)
            , begin(begin_)
            { }
        StringRangeProxy(const StringRangeProxy&) = default;

        String operator[](size_t end) const{
            return String(src.data + begin, size_t(end - begin));
        }
    };

    StringRangeProxy  operator[](size_t begin) const{
        return StringRangeProxy (*this, begin);
    } 
};
```

Еще лучше использовать `std::string_view` или аналог для результата, т.к. для работы с подстрокой не нужна ее полная копия, достаточно указателя на начало и размера.

Comment: Спасибо. Про паттерн proxy до этого не слышал, но по сути моя идея такая же, только вместо ссылки на строку передаю си строку. Лишнее глубокое копирование Вы имеете ввиду, когда возвращается копия StringRangeProxy (*this, begin) в первом [], и копия String(src.data + begin, size_t(end - begin)) при втором []?

Answer (score 1):

Известный мне строковой класс:

```
using String = std::string;
```

Теперь  мой класс будет просто его наследником, чтобы не повторять код, и будет иметь тип помощник для своего оператора:

```
class My_String : public String {
    struct proxy {
        const String& s;
        proxy(const String& str) : s(str) {}
        String::difference_type start{};
        String operator[](string::difference_type off)
        {
            if (off < start) off = start;
            return s.substr(start, off - start);
        }
    };
public:
    My_String(const char* str) : String(str) {}
    //по необходимости добавьте другие конструкторы
    //а оператор вернет помощника
    proxy operator [](const string::difference_type off) const
    {
        proxy p(*this);
        p.start = off;
        return p;
    }
};

int main() {    
    My_String str("test program");
    cout << str[5][12] << ' ' << str[0][5]; //вывод: program test
    return 0;
}
```